# Testing user logs in with Rspec in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rspec

I'm trying to test the authentication method that I've implemented in my project. I have not used Devise or Doorkeeper but a solution I've found on Internet. Testing the register action is easy because I check in database that the user has been created succesfully. But I'm not sure how to check the user is been logged in succesfully. After doing a little research I've decided to check that when user logs in, the session[:user_id] matches the user.id. Debugging in console I can see that they both match, but when I try to launch the test it returns me nil and I don't know why. Thank you in advance

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user, :only => [:home, :profile, :setting]
  before_filter :save_login_state, :only => [:login, :login_attempt]

  def login
  end

  def login_attempt
    puts "I get here"
    authorized_user = User.authenticate(params[:email],params[:password])
    if authorized_user
      session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
      flash[:notice] = "Wow Welcome again, you logged in as #{authorized_user.username}"
      redirect_to(:action => 'profile')
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid Username or Password"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
      render "login"
    end
  end

  def logout
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to :action => 'login'
  end

  def profile
  end

end
```

sessions_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'Login route' do
  it "a user logs in with email and password when registered" do
    post "/register", {
      username: "David",
      email: "testingemail@gmail.com",
      encrypted_password: "secret101"
    }

    post "/login_attempt", {
      email: "testingemail@gmail.com",
      password: "secret101"
    }

    user_id = User.first.id
    puts user_id

    expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(user_id)
  end
end
```

This is the result I get

Failure/Error: expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(user_id)

```
   expected: BSON::ObjectId('56a7a1b0e389a21fb8f3e07a')
        got: nil
```

Comment: Did you check that the test indeed authorises the user properly?

Comment: As I sidenote I feel I have to mention that implementing your own authentication is a VERY BAD IDEA and you should rather use an existing solution.

Comment: Not being able to easily test sounds like a smell to me. What about implementing a current_user method that is available in all your controllers that's nil if the user isn't logged in? Also, I agree with Michal that rolling your own auth is a bad idea for anything other than a learning experience.

Comment: I'm agree with you both about using an existing solution, but I wanted to understand the process better than I did. The solution is that I can't access to session['user_id] in test the way I was trying to. I needed to get the session through last_request.env['rack.session'] and the test passes. Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem is that I can't access to the session in test by the way I was trying to. I needed to do something like this

```
session_id = last_request.env['rack.session']['user_id']
```